Spark Joins (Pyspark API) - specifying join columns - some approaches hit recursion limit and others do not?
I'm joining some largish datasets using PySpark:

df1 row count = 50673
df2 row count = 45356

The example snippet of code being used is below, just commenting things in/out to help with investigating this problem and separating out the variables. The join is always a left inner, i.e. of this form:

join_df_left.join(join_df_right,_________,how = 'inner')

The code block is:
join_list_common_cols = ['example_col']
join_list_leftdf_cols = ['col1']
join_list_rightdf_cols = ['col2']

join_df_left = df1.alias('dfL')
join_df_right = df2.alias('dfR')

keyCol1 = join_df_left.select(*join_list_leftdf_cols)
keyCol2 = join_df_right.select(*join_list_rightdf_cols)

df_joint = (
    join_df_left.join(
        join_df_right,
        #join_df_right.hint("broadcast"),
        on=(join_df_left['col1']==join_df_right['col2']),
        #on=(keyCol1==keyCol2),
        #on=('dfL.col1'=='dfR.col2'),
        how = "inner"
    )
)

If I do this inner join it works fine when:

using spark sql
using the syntax to specify the key columns that is uncommented: on=join_df_left['col1']==join_df_right['col2']

Specifically, the syntax in point 2 above parses fine and flows data fine (the problem becomes apparent only once it's actually trying to generate the data for the df_joint dataframe, the other two 'on=...' syntaxes work up until that point.
If I use either of the other two to specify the columns to join on, then when I try to actually display the joint df (df_joint.limit(5).display()), it hits pythons recursion limit (which I've set to 3000 for this experiment, but obviously still not enough).
I'm trying to understand why, even though all three syntax's for specifying the join columns parse fine, two of them seem to hit the recursion limit when you actually try to get the data evaluated, even though I believe they are acting on the same data and should be the same query under the hood?

Alright, deeply suspicious that this is caused by the type of object that I'm trying to feed to the 'on=' parameter of the dataframe join method. The last two cases for  (i.e. on=KeyCol1 or on='dfL.col1) are trying to operate on a single column dataframe, rather than an instance of pyspark.sql.connect.column.Column which is what the df1['col1'] style of referencing returns.

keyCol1 is a dataframe, not a column name
